# ¿Como uso la estructura IF?

Tags: php

Ejercicio07.- Realice un programa en PHP que determine si una persona de 25 años es mayor de edad o no y muestra el mensaje correspondiente

Ejercicio08.- Realiza un programa que tenga como valores iniciales, tu nombre y tu fecha de nacimiento y muéstralos en pantalla con el formato (lo que esta en letra minúscula, itálica en color guida, debes sustituirlo por valores reales obtenidos por las funciones de PHP):
YO nombre NACÍ EL día DE mes DE año Y TENGO edad AÑOS DE EDAD

Ejercicio09.- Realiza un programa en PHP que genere un número entero positivo aleatorio, lo muestre en pantalla y determine si es un número Non o Par

Ejercicio10.- Crear un programa que salude al usuario desplegando buenos días (de 5:00 am a 12:00 md), buenas tardes (de 12:01 pm a 7:00 pm) o buenas noches (de 7:01 pm a 4:59 am)

Answer (score 1):

En PHP `if` permite la ejecución condicional de fragmentos de código. Si la expresión se evalúa como TRUE, PHP ejecutará la sentencia y si se evalúa como FALSE la ignorará.

Mas info en [Manual PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.if.php)

El primer ejercicio se podria resolver asi:

```
<?php
$edad = 25;

if($edad >= 21){
   echo 'Juan es mayor de edad';
} else {
   echo 'Juan es menor de edad';
}
?>
```

Primero declaro la variable `$edad` con un valor de `25`. Despues siguiendo con la determinacion de PHP ejecuto el condicional para saber si `$edad` es mayor o igual a 21; `$edad >= 21`, en donde 21 es el numero que determina la mayoria de edad de una persona.

En este caso la expresión evalúa TRUE, `$edad` es mayor a 21 entonce como resultado obtengo que `Juan es mayor de edad`.

Si la variable `$edad` tendria el valor de 18 el resultado seria que `Juan es menor de edad`

Y si el valor de `$edad` es 21 el resultado seria que `Juan es mayor de edad` ya que habia determinado que edad sea mayor o igual a 21.

Creo que con esta informacion, tu podrias realizar el resto de los ejercicios sin problemas.